# How to manage sub-packages (just like Laravel does) with composer?

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php

Looking at the composer.json file on [Laravel/Framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) on Github, I realize that Laravel utilizing the `replace` property of composer to allow the user not have to install the same component twice.

But every sub-package has its own git repository on GitHub, and the version number also matches to the main package [Laravel/Framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework).

So the main package and the sub-package has the same source code on GitHub.

for example:  [`src/Illuminate/Pagination/` in laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.3/src/Illuminate/Pagination) has the same code on [illuminate/pagination](https://github.com/illuminate/pagination).

And all the sub-packages that included within the main package don't have a `.gitmodules`.

I'm confusing now... how could the maintainer sync the source code to the individual sub-package from the main package? or perhaps sync the main package's sub-package from the git repository of those individual sub-packages?